# MacBook Air for Java/J2EE/RoR kind of development work?

Tags: java, macos

How far **MacBook Air** is suitable for developers?
Can it handle running Eclipse, JDK, Flex Builder, Apache, Tomcat and couple of usual applications together and still perform well ?

Or is it purely for business people?

Comment: Probably a superuser.com question ?

Comment: Rather an AskDifferent question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suitable yes in the sense that it is above the "minimum system requirements". I've ran (older) versions of Eclipse and J2EE on much slower machines. I still recoil when I think of the time I tried to build distributed Eclipse plug-ins on an IBM T20.

Are you going to enjoy it and be very productive on it? I would bet not. You probably want more cores, more memory, etc. Developers are also prone to loss of concentration, so an added delay when switching windows, starting debugs, etc. will affect your performance.

In addition, I would highly recommend against trying to do full-time dev on a 13" screen. If you have to use your laptop screen, go with at least 15" with a decent resolution. IDEs require resolution these days because of the sidebars.

For about the same cost you can get a 15" MBP, better bang for the money. Core i5 in the new MBPs is also better structured for multithreading, IMHO, than the core 2 duos.

Comment: I may be in the fringe but I exclusively use a 13" MB as my dev machine. While more screen real estate would be nice, I've gotten quite used to it. But most of the time when I'm at home I'm using an external monitor (17" LCD) for extra real estate. With respect to working with Java, the initial 2GB was not cutting it. Java is a f*cking beast when it comes to memory. Running Eclipse, XCode, and a java-based data store killed it. Definitely need at least 4GB (which is a potential upgrade on a MBA).

Comment: To add: the 2010 13" MB Air has a resolution almost equivalent to the 2011 15" MB Pros.

Answer (score 5):

I have been using a 13" MB (before they became pros) with 4GB/2GHZ Core 2 Duo for some time now for work with Eclipse, XCode, Cassandra, Apache/Tomcat and Photoshop. Here is my take away:

- Screen size: At times I wish I had more but you learn to become a minimalist with all the windows available and use the hiding option on most of them. Major annoyances are typically having to go back and forth between dev environment and Console. Most of the time I code from home where I have an external monitor which solves all of this.
- Speed: The CPU is sufficient but the memory is not if you're doing major dev work with Java. Java is a memory-whore. I started with 2GB but had to upgrade to 4GB. Typically this was when I was working with Eclipse and had the whole stack running on my machine (app server, data store, dev environment). I've read that MBAs are upgradable to 4GB but it's soldered on in which case you should order the upgrade directly from Apple to be safe (whereas with MBPs you can do it yourself no problem).
- Convenience: My 13" MB is light. But, I don't know if it's age or spending too much time coding, I find myself wishing it was even lighter especially when I fly somewhere.

All in all, I'd be willing to switch to a MBA if cost weren't an issue. Another thing to keep in mind is that you'd have to be OK with working on high-resolution laptop on a smaller screen. It's worth going to the Apple Store to see it with your own eyes.

Answer (score 3):

What about the new MacBook Air Model? The 13" inch version with 4GB RAM and 2,x GHz cpu should do it.

The SSD/FLash will be the performance booster in this model.

Comment: In particular, I've noticed that on my MB (with 4GB) paging can significantly reduce response times. While I have enough memory, go from one dev environment to another and it's really freaking annoying. I imagine the flash-based storage would do away with this annoyance.

Answer (score 1):

I used to do software development on an iBook with a 1.42GHz processor and 1GB of RAM, so I'm pretty sure the MacBook Air will be more than adequate. :)

To give a more technical analysis: The Air has a relatively slower processor than, say, a MacBook Pro, and less RAM (in its standard configuration), but it should still be more than adequate for development work.

Whether the MacBook Air is worth its price tag (especially compared to a MacBook or MacBook Pro) is a different story. :)

Comment: Be careful. That little sucker gets hot when you get busy on it!

Comment: So you mean, you dont work with Java in your iBook. I am thinking and confused between 13" MBA or 15" MBP and I want to develop on it Java hardly. So maybe 13" MBA may not handle the development tools and IDEs or enviroment. I am really confused.

Comment: @Fatih: I did use it for Java development, once upon a time.

Comment: OK, so its 2011 and the Sandy Bridge MBA's have just been announced and since Im in the market for a Mac laptop I was wondering if anyone has had a chance to try the new machines for development?

Specifically, Im looking to do Android, iOS and some web development on it. Im concerned that 4Gb RAM and Core i5/i7 may not cut it (I used to use an older dual-core 17" MBP with 4Gb RAM for Android development and that was not exactly a speed demon). Any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that if you're happy to consider using a laptop as your development machine then you'll probably be fine with a MacBook Air.

In my opinion, monitors, mouse, keyboard far outweigh any processing power.

Comment: I wouldn't say far outweigh _any_ processing power, but yes, they are very important factors to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

I've got one. It's pretty fast, the SSD makes a lot of difference compared to the standard MBP laptops. I run IntelliJ on it. MBP is a bit faster with building the projects and I feel that IntelliJ sometimes is a bit sluggish, but it's OK.

I think it's a proper dev machine. We're typing text most of the time :-) We're not rendering video or 3D scenes. All devs I know that have one, are really happy with it. So yes, but it.